# Not able to get exact latest records with two columns having same value - in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get distinct records for a specific department from the table `employee`.

I have tried with this code in SQL Server, and I'm getting this error:

> Error: employeeId is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

My code:

```
SELECT 
    name, department, MAX(jointime) LatestDate, employeeId
FROM 
    employee 
WHERE
    department = 'Mechanical'
GROUP BY 
    name
```

Records in DB:

```
name    department           joinTime            EmployeeId
-----------------------------------------------------------
Erik    Mechanical           2019-07-06 11:59:59    456
Tom     Mechanical           2019-07-06 11:59:59    789
Erik    Computer             2019-07-05 11:59:59    222
Erik    Computer             2019-07-04 11:59:59    111
Erik    Mechanical           2019-07-01 11:59:59    123
```

I want to achieve the result when a query for 'Mechanical' is executed. The latest record should be fetched from DB for a particular department.

```
name    department           joinTime            EmployeeId
-----------------------------------------------------------
Erik    Mechanical    2019-07-06 11:59:59     456
Tom     Mechanical    2019-07-06 11:59:59     789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EXISTS:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employee e
WHERE e.department='Mechanical'
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM employee
  WHERE department = e.department
  AND name = e.name AND joinTime > e.joinTime
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a7a555f462b276c384a5245d0442f3a1).
Results:

```
> name | department | joinTime            | EmployeeId
> :--- | :--------- | :------------------ | ---------:
> Erik | Mechanical | 2019-07-06 11:59:59 |        456
> Tom  | Mechanical | 2019-07-06 11:59:59 |        789
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the key is [Name] and not [EmployeeId]

One option is the WITH TIES clause, and thus no need for aggregation

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 with ties * 
 From  employee
 Where department='Mechanical'
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By [Name] order by joinTime Desc)
```

**Returns**

```
name    department  joinTime                 EmployeeId
Erik    Mechanical  2019-07-06 11:59:59.000  456
Tom     Mechanical  2019-07-06 11:59:59.000  789
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER to mark the latest row for each employee, or CROSS APPLY to run a correlated subquery for each employee.

```
with q as
(
    SELECT name, department, jointime, employeeId, 
           row_number() over (partition by name, order by joinTime desc) rn
    FROM employee where  department='Mechanical'
)
select name, department, jointime, employeeId
from q
where rn = 1
```

or

```
with emp as
(
  select distinct name from employee
)
select e.*
from q
cross apply
(
  select top 1 * 
  from employee e2 
  where e2.name = q.name
  order by joinDate desc
) e
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AGGREGATE Functions for fields which are used in `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT name, 
  MIN(department)
, MAX(jointime) LatestDate, 
, MIN(employeeId)
FROM employee where  department='Mechanical'
GROUP BY name
```

SQL server finds all records with names `Tom` or `Erik`, but SQL Server does not know what one value from multiple rows should be chosen for the fields such as `department` or `employeeId`. By using aggregrate functions, you are advising SQL Server to get the `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, `COUNT` values of that columns.

OR use those columns to the GROUP BY clause to get all unique rows:

```
SELECT name 
    , department
    , jointime 
    , employeeId
    FROM employee where  department='Mechanical'
    GROUP BY  name
            , department
            , jointime 
            , employeeId
```

Comment: What if an employee joined in Department Z, and later changed to Department A?

Answer (score 0):

Just add department,employeeId to the GROUP BY

```
SELECT name , department,   MAX(jointime) LatestDate , employeeId
FROM employee where  department='Mechanical'
GROUP BY name, department, employeeId
```